# How to get random value from a subset of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am making primitive anime generator. I know how to get just random value from the list. I want to ask the user which genre of anime he'd like to watch using `input` function and then get random value only for animes that have the genre that you user entered in input.

I've written this code:

```
import random

anime_list = [
    ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood', 'Action', 'Fantasy'],
    ['Mob Psycho 100', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Kill la Kill', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Spy x Family', 'Action', 'Comedy'],
    ['Black Lagoon', 'Action']
    ]

print('What genre do you want to watch?')
genre = input()
```

I guess here I need to use for loop but i don't know what exactly.

```
print(random.choice(anime_list))
```

I got the random value but how to get random value from the anime with 'Comedy' string in it?

Comment: Does efficiency matter here?  You have the wrong data structure if it does.

Answer (score 1):

A list of lists is the wrong data structure for this application. Since you want to *look up* titles by genre, you should use a dictionary, where the genre specifies the key, and the value is a list of all titles that belong to that genre.

Now, we run into a problem: since you want to look up by a *single* genre and a title can belong to multiple genres, such a dictionary might repeat titles. For example, you might have:

```
anime_genre_dict = {"Action": ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood', 'Mob Psycho 100', ... , 'Black Lagoon'],
                    "Comedy": ['Mob Psycho 100', 'Kill la Kill', ...],
                    "Fantasy": ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood', ...]
                   }
```

This makes it harder to define your library of animes. Instead of doing it manually, we can write code to translate your `anime_list`:

```
anime_genre_dict = {}

for title, *genres in anime_list:
    # Since one title can have multiple genres, we want to add it to 
    # our dict for each genre
    for genre in genres:
        # I set the genre to lowercase to allow us to look up the genre 
        # regardless of the case of the user input
        genre = genre.lower()

        # If we haven't encountered this genre yet, we need to create an 
        # empty list for it in our lookup dictionary
        if genre not in anime_genre_dict:
            anime_genre_dict[genre] = []

        # Append the title to the correct list
        anime_genre_dict[genre].append(title)
```

Now, our list of lists has been converted to a dict that we can look up conveniently by genre:

```
{'action': ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood',
  'Mob Psycho 100',
  'Kill la Kill',
  'Spy x Family',
  'Black Lagoon'],
 'fantasy': ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood'],
 'comedy': ['Mob Psycho 100', 'Kill la Kill', 'Spy x Family']}
```

Remember, this needs to be done **only once**, and then you can ask the user for genres as many times as you want:

```
# Infinite loop, keep looping until we break
while True:
    # Ask the user for input, convert to lowercase because our dict
    # has lowercase keys
    user_genre = input("What genre would you like to watch? (or exit) ").lower()
    # Note that input can take the prompt for the user, so you don't need to print it first

    # If the user has had enough, break out of the loop
    if user_genre == "exit":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break

    try:
        # Get the titles for the selected genre
        titles = anime_genre_dict[user_genre]
    except KeyError:
        # If the key doesn't exist in the dict, a KeyError is raised
        # We can catch that error and print a nice message
        print("Sorry, I don't know any titles in that genre")

        # Skip the rest of the loop, and ask user again
        continue

    # Select a random value from the selected genre, and print it
    selected_title = random.choice(titles)
    print(f"My suggestion: {selected_title}")
```

This would print, for example:

```
What genre would you like to watch? (or exit) comedy
My suggestion: Spy x Family

What genre would you like to watch? (or exit) fantasy
My suggestion: Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood

What genre would you like to watch? (or exit) romance
Sorry, I don't know any titles in that genre

What genre would you like to watch? (or exit) exit
Goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

anime_list = [
    ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood', 'Action', 'Fantasy'],
    ['Mob Psycho 100', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Kill la Kill', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Spy x Family', 'Action', 'Comedy'],
    ['Black Lagoon', 'Action']
    ]

random.choice(list(filter(lambda movie_details: "Comedy" in movie_details, anime_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before random.choice(), build another list that contains all items of the selected genre:

```py
genre_list = [anime for anime in anime_list if genre in anime]
print(random.choice(genre_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop to iterate over the anime list and check if each anime has the desired genre.

```
import random
    
anime_list = [
    ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood', 'Action', 'Fantasy'],
    ['Mob Psycho 100', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Kill la Kill', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Spy x Family', 'Action', 'Comedy'],
    ['Black Lagoon', 'Action']
]

print('What genre do you want to watch?')
genre = input()

matching_anime = []
for anime in anime_list:
    if genre in anime:
        matching_anime.append(anime)

if matching_anime:
    random_anime = random.choice(matching_anime)
    print( random_anime[0])
else:
    print(' wrong genre.')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can use a `for` loop to extract every entry that matches the chosen genre, adding each one to a new list.

Then from the list of extracted entries use `random.choice()` to choose one randomly.

Your code:

```py
import random

anime_list = [
    ['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood', 'Action', 'Fantasy'],
    ['Mob Psycho 100', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Kill la Kill', 'Action', 'Comedy'], 
    ['Spy x Family', 'Action', 'Comedy'],
    ['Black Lagoon', 'Action']
    ]

print('What genre do you want to watch?')
genre = input()
```

Code for choosing randomly picking a series out of those that have the chosen genre:

```py
# To hold all the anime series with the chosen genre.
results = []

# Iterate over each anime entry
for a in anime_list:
    
    # Get the genres of the current entry (second element onwards)
    a_genres = a[1:]
    
    # If the chosen genre is found in it, add the name of the series (first element) to the results. 
    if genre in a_genres:
        results.append(a[0])
        

# Make sure to check that there were actually series that had the genre.
if len(results) > 0:
    
    # Use the random.choice method to randomly select an element from the results list.
    random_anime = random.choice(results)

    print("List of series under the " + genre + " genre:")
    print(results)
    print("\nRandom series:", random_anime)
    
else:
    print("No series under the " + genre + " genre.")
```

#### Examples:

Suppose `genre = "Comedy"`:

```
List of series under the Comedy genre:
['Mob Psycho 100', 'Kill la Kill', 'Spy x Family']

Random series: Spy x Family
```

Now suppose `genre = "Fantasy"`:

```
List of series under the Fantasy genre:
['Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood']

Random series: Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood
```

Now suppose `genre = "Adventure"`:

```
No series under the Adventure genre.
```